# How to use email address only while replying mails in thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird, exchange

I want to configure Thunderbird client so that when I do reply or reply all, it should use email addresses only from original mails and not names.

I have attached screenshot for reference.I want `My, Friend <jake.doe@example.com>` to be `jake.doe@example.com` and `@SOME  DL <grp@example.com>` to be `grp@example.com.`

I need help on this because I am using Thunderbird to access exchange mail server. And DL on server configured such a way that they have @ symbol at the beginning and spaces in names. Example

```
 @SOME DL NAME <address@example.com>
```

Now when I do reply to them my my message fails and sometime add double quotes in between address and names.

[image: https://i.imgsafe.org/7f19777694.png]

Comment: Why are you using Thunderbird for MS Exchange and not Outlook?

Comment: I don't have outlook in my machine.
Also I like thunderbird.